# JS bundles do not render without EnableOptimization set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it's probably a bug inside MVC4. I wonder how can I fix this?

### Working scenario

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ScriptBundle scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/js");
        string[] scriptArray =
        {
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        };
        scriptBundle.Include(scriptArray);
        scriptBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/content/js", "*.js");
        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

`@Scripts.Render("~/js")`

*Converts to (e.g. IT WORKS!)*

`<script src="/js?v=VeCPNK561DZp34yjmWbLrNM35Kf6gaNDl0xsMMC25BQ1"></script>`

### Not so much working scenario

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ScriptBundle scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/js");
        string[] scriptArray =
        {
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/content/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        };
        scriptBundle.Include(scriptArray);
        scriptBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/content/js", "*.js");
        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);

        // BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; // I could set it to 'false' for same result, it's false by default
    }
}
```

`@Scripts.Render("~/js")`

*Converts to (e.g. IT DOES NOT WORK!)*

`(nothing, couple of empty break lines)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you should define your bundles using the "non-min" JavaScript files. When you enable optimizations it will swap the non-min files for the min files for you:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        ScriptBundle scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/js");
        string[] scriptArray =
        {
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.0.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/content/plugins/jquery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/content/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js",
        };
        scriptBundle.Include(scriptArray);
        scriptBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/content/js", "*.js");
        bundles.Add(scriptBundle);
    }
}
```

Optimizations are set to false when debugging, but are true by default in release mode.

Comment: Yes but they will not show anyway, do you think it does not show them just because they have word "min" in their filename? That would be rather dull.

Comment: Have you tried it? If I add `.min` to the filenames and turn optimizations off - I get no scripts.

Comment: Yes, and you are correct. It works when I have no `min` in file names. Thanks :)

Comment: You can leave the .min files in there, but be sure to add `bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();` otherwise they will be ignored.

Comment: @JonathanStrate, I did this - `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/admin").IncludeDirectory("~/content/css", "*.min.css"));` </br> `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();` But still CSS not loaded.

Answer (score 8):

yes, It doesn't work properly with files like *.min.js.

> "if you add a file to your bundle that has a name that ends in .min.js
>   (like I did) and optimizations aren’t enabled (e.g. debug is set to
>   true in web.config and BundleTable.EnableOptimizations has not been
>   set to true), this file will be ignored (i.e no script include will be
>   generated for it in your html)."

Here you can read full original response:
http://blog.degree.no/2013/06/javascript-file-missing-resource-bundle-asp-net-web-optimization-framework/