# How can i increase Asp.net Page optimization

Tags: asp.net, .net

- How you can i increase asp.net page optimization ?
- How to maintain the security level in asp.net ?
- How can i use Bundle in Asp.net 4.0 ?

**i know that we can use the bundle  in Asp.net 4.0 MVC....**

**i need to know how we can use in Asp.net 4.0**

Can you guide me to achieve this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

While the description is for MVC it works for all ASP.NET stack (WebForms as well).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i need to download the Bundler framework, or else bundler.dll file it enough to integrate ?

Comment: i have downloaded the System.Web.Optimization.dll file,

Comment: I suggest getting it via nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Optimization/0.1.0

Comment: for this i have posted question, please check this guide me to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299540/bundling-minification-not-applying-css-js-using-asp-net-4-0-c-sharp/21299573?noredirect=1#21299573)

Comment: If all else fails you can simply set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

Comment: Link to the above sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458642/js-bundles-do-not-render-without-enableoptimization-set-to-true